# CSS issue in Symfony2 "PROD" environment

Tags: jquery, css, symfony

I am having css issues in Symfony2 in prod environment where all the local css files are merged into single css file.

Below is the css order :

```
{% stylesheets '../app/Resources/public/css/bootstrap/*'
                       '../app/Resources/public/css/*'
                       '../app/Resources/public/css/jquery_ui/*'
                       '../app/Resources/public/errata/css/*'
                       '../vendor/isteven/angular-multi-select/angular-multi-select.css'
           filter='cssrewrite' %}
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
```

**jQuery UI Dialog box is not opening in prod environment.**

Comment: @Downvoter : Please add your comment..

Comment: Are you dumping the assets via php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug?

Comment: Used command to install and dump : `sudo  php app/console --env=prod assets:install --symlink
sudo  php app/console --env=prod assetic:dump`

Comment: So, when you dump the files, are they generated properly? Can the browser load them? Does the browser throw any JS errors?